# Intellij / libGDX adding lib kryo NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to add the lib from esotericsoftware "Kryo" to my libGDX project on the Desktop and Android module. I'm using Intellij.

What I tried:

- Adding the kryo-3.0 folder to the External Libraries
- Adding the dependencies in build.gradle to all modules 
  `compile "com.esotericsoftware:kryo:3.0.3"`
- Run the Gradle
- Sync Project.

What I got after compile the Desktop module:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/strategy/InstantiatorStrategy
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:131)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objenesis/strategy/InstantiatorStrategy
  at com.projectbeta.deepdarkness.screens.MenuScreen.show(MenuScreen.java:18)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
  at com.projectbeta.deepdarkness.DeepDarkness.create(DeepDarkness.java:16)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objenesis.strategy.InstantiatorStrategy
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested and it works, paste that into root `gradle.build` of your project (not in some of the module specific) and resync.

```
project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        ......
        compile group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryo', version: '3.0.3'
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        .......
        compile group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryo', version: '3.0.3'

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        ......
        compile group: 'com.esotericsoftware', name: 'kryo', version: '3.0.3'

    }
}
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem. Im not using maven. In the README from kryo is a information if your project doesn't use maven add 2 libs (minLog and Objenesis). Also the android module should not compile these libs. I only got it work on android without compile the libs.

Comment: But it's not maven, but gradle. And your exception basically saying that one of the library is not resolved during application runtime. Since your libgdx project uses gradle I can't see any reason to add kryo libs manually